# Getting Exception when updating Maven Project?

Tags: eclipse, maven, jboss

I am getting below exception when updating Maven project,try to add some helper projects.

> Could not initialize class
>   org.jboss.tools.portlet.core.internal.project.facet.PortletPostInstallListener

I am using `apache-maven-3.3.3`, `Kepler Service Release 2`, `Java7`

Comment: What have you updated?

Comment: I am setup the project nothing else in a new workspace

Comment: Is it a build message by a test or is a runtime problem?

Comment: Its not a Build Message I am doing `Maven->Update the Project`

Comment: So you are in an IDE (Eclipse?)...first you have to get working your build on command line...

Comment: Yes i am in eclipse Build is working fine from outside

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and solved it by adding an "EJB Module" facet in Project > Properties > Project Facets.

I only had "JBoss Maven Integration" and "Java" facets selected (my project does not use Portlets). As none of the "JBoss Maven Integration" required facets were selected, my guess is that this facet try to autodetect the correct facet by looping over all possible facets.

Comment: EJB module? Why to add it when i am not using it

Comment: Do you use the "JBoss Maven Integration" facet? If yes, this facet requires one of the following facets: "Application Client module 1.2 or newer", "Dynamic Web Module 2.5 or newer", "EAR 5.0 or newer", "EJB Module 3.0 or newer", "JCA Module 1.0 or newer", "Utility Module", "Web Fragment Module 3.0 or newer". Do you use any of these facets?

Comment: May Be JBoss Maven Integration downloaded but i am not using it anywhere i am using Maven outside from Jboss tools